# Make a Row of rotated Text in Jetpack compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I want to make a `Row` of -90 degrees rotated `Text` Composables to make something like below:

[image: a row of rotated texts]

However this code (**repro case**):

```kotlin
@Preview(showBackground = true, backgroundColor = 0xffffffff)
@Composable
fun Preview_Row_With_Rotated_Text() {
    Row {
        Text(
            text = "A text",
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(2.dp)
                .rotate(-90f),
            maxLines = 1,
        )
        Text(
            text = "A text which is a bit longer",
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(2.dp)
                .rotate(-90f),
            maxLines = 1,
        )
        Text(
            text = "A text which is kinda longer than previous one",
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(2.dp)
                .rotate(-90f),
            maxLines = 1,
        )
    }
}
```

produces this:

[image: result of row of texts]

The `Row` uses old width of `Text` composables (the width of non-rotated Text) to place them one after another.

Where is the reason of this problem?

Answer (score 8):

You can try using it in a `Column` and then rotating that `Column` by `-90f`:

```
@Composable
fun Main() {
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .width(200.dp)
            .rotate(-90f)
    ) {
        MyText(text = "Financial Advice")
        MyText(text = "Strategy and Marketing")
        MyText(text = "Information Technology")
    }
}

@Composable
fun MyText(text: String) {
    Text(
        text = text,
        modifier = Modifier
            .padding(4.dp)
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .background(MaterialTheme.colors.secondary)
            .padding(16.dp),
        textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
        maxLines = 1
    )
}
```

[image]