# How to show vertical text with proper size/layout in jetpack compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

How does one properly rotate text in jetpack compose and get it to do a correct layout? When I use the `rotate` modifier on a Text object the text is rotated but the size taken up in the layout seems to be using the pre-rotated text width.

Here is a simple example of what I am trying to accomplish - the vertical text should be along the left side in a narrow space:

```
@Composable
fun MainBox() {
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
    ) {
        Text(
            modifier = Modifier.padding(4.dp).background(Color.Gray),
            text = "This is at the top"
        )

        Row(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth().weight(1f),
            verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
        ) {

            Text(
                modifier = Modifier.padding(4.dp).rotate(-90f),
                text = "This should be vertical text on the left side"
            )

            Text(
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize().background(Color.Yellow),
                textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
                text = "This is a big yellow box that should take up most of the space"
            )
        }
    }
}
```

However, what this shows is this.

[image: long vertical text]

If I shorten the text in the vertical text it only takes up a narrow space, which looks more like the layout I want.

[image: short vertical text]

Is there a way to intercept the layout process or some other setting to use to fix the sizes so that the vertical text takes up only one text row's width of horizontal space, but still adapts to user font size changes (so no fixed sizes)?

Answers to similar questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62767755/how-to-stack-text-vertically-with-rotation-using-jetpack-compose) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66705884/make-a-row-of-rotated-text-in-jetpack-compose) do not solve this problem or no longer work.

Comment: Maybe if you create a custom layout? -> https://developer.android.com/codelabs/jetpack-compose-layouts?authuser=1&continue=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Fcourses%2Fpathways%2Fcompose%3Fauthuser%3D1%23codelab-https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Fcodelabs%2Fjetpack-compose-layouts#6

Comment: @F.Mysir I tried that following that same example and just swapping width and height but the text disappeared entirely then. That seems like a plausible path though - I'm just not sure how to do it.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

My version. After a few tests it seems to work pretty well

```kotlin
class ComposeActivity7 : ComponentActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        setContent {
            ComposeTutorialTheme {

                Column(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
                ) {
                    Text(
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .padding(4.dp)
                            .background(Color.Gray),
                        text = "This is at the top"
                    )

                    Row(
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .fillMaxWidth()
                            .weight(1f),
                        verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
                    ) {
                        Text(
                            modifier = Modifier
                                .vertical()
                                .rotate(-90f)
                                .background(Color.Gray)
                                .padding(4.dp),
                            text = "This should be vertical text on the left side"
                        )
                        Text(
                            modifier = Modifier
                                .fillMaxSize()
                                .background(Color.Yellow),
                            textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
                            text = "This is a big yellow box that should take up most of the space"
                        )
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

fun Modifier.vertical() =
    layout { measurable, constraints ->
        val placeable = measurable.measure(constraints)
        layout(placeable.height, placeable.width) {
            placeable.place(
                x = -(placeable.width / 2 - placeable.height / 2),
                y = -(placeable.height / 2 - placeable.width / 2)
            )
        }
    }
```

**Result**

[image]

Comment: Perfect! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Slightly improved variant of Sergei S, which works within parents which have `Modifier.high(Intrinsic.X)`:

```kotlin
fun Modifier.rotateVertically(rotation: VerticalRotation) = then(
    object : LayoutModifier {
        override fun MeasureScope.measure(measurable: Measurable, constraints: Constraints): MeasureResult {
            val placeable = measurable.measure(constraints)
            return layout(placeable.height, placeable.width) {
                placeable.place(
                    x = -(placeable.width / 2 - placeable.height / 2),
                    y = -(placeable.height / 2 - placeable.width / 2)
                )
            }
        }

        override fun IntrinsicMeasureScope.minIntrinsicHeight(measurable: IntrinsicMeasurable, width: Int): Int {
            return measurable.maxIntrinsicWidth(width)
        }

        override fun IntrinsicMeasureScope.maxIntrinsicHeight(measurable: IntrinsicMeasurable, width: Int): Int {
            return measurable.maxIntrinsicWidth(width)
        }

        override fun IntrinsicMeasureScope.minIntrinsicWidth(measurable: IntrinsicMeasurable, height: Int): Int {
            return measurable.minIntrinsicHeight(height)
        }

        override fun IntrinsicMeasureScope.maxIntrinsicWidth(measurable: IntrinsicMeasurable, height: Int): Int {
            return measurable.maxIntrinsicHeight(height)
        }
    })
    .then(rotate(rotation.value))

enum class VerticalRotation(val value: Float) {
    CLOCKWISE(90f), COUNTER_CLOCKWISE(270f)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Improved version of Sergei S's answer that combines the `rotate` and `vertical` modifiers into one, to make it easier to use

```
fun Modifier.rotateVertically(clockwise: Boolean = true): Modifier {
    val rotate = rotate(if (clockwise) 90f else -90f)
    
    val adjustBounds = layout { measurable, constraints ->
        val placeable = measurable.measure(constraints)
        layout(placeable.height, placeable.width) {
            placeable.place(
                x = -(placeable.width / 2 - placeable.height / 2),
                y = -(placeable.height / 2 - placeable.width / 2)
            )
        }
    }
    return rotate then adjustBounds
}
```

Use it like this:

```
Text(
    text = "I'm going to be rotated clockwise",
    modifier = Modifier.rotateVertically()
)
```